Laravel private file serving pending problem
I save some photos privately in the storage and show them to the user when needed using the following method.
in route :
Route::get('/serveFile/{address?}', [FileController::class, 'serveFile'])
->where('address', '.*')->name('serveFile');

in controller :
public function serveFile($address = null)
{
    return response()->file(storage_path($address));
}

finally, the src of the photo or file or ... is placed in the html as follows:
https://DOMAIN/serveFile/app/DIRECTORYNAME/2024/06/15/DIRECTORYNAME/NAME.jpg

Everything is good and there is no problem in loading and working logic. Only when I want to show a large number of images, the browser puts them in a queue and makes them pending and loads the images two by two.
look at this picture :

Images with lazy load and without it, both modes have problems.
What is wrong?
i tried changing controller code and increasing CPU count and change hosting. nothing changed.
i need some advise :)

Do you generate <img src="..."> tags?

@Olivier of course. as you can see in the picture , images loading and functionality is ok . the problem is pending !

How many parallel connections does your server allow? Would this also happen when requesting a large number of static files (such that neither PHP nor Laravel are involved)? Is this problem related to a specific browser?

@NicoHaase its not related to a specific browser. how can i check parallel connections ?

@Afshar check this. do you have any ad block?

The first eight from those writers:940 images have been loaded regularly? Or did they also load two by two?

The way you do this carries a huge security risk. Never just trust input from the user. The way you wrote this code users can potentially request files they should not have access to. You're better off making database entries for files with their path, and then passing the id of those entries to your controller instead of the path.

@francisco its not about chrome ( I don't have ad blocker extension ) . the problem exists in every browser.

@brombeer all images will be loaded successfully. but they are a queue and load two by two .

As @Sitethief pointed out: beware of path traversal attacks.

@Sitethief i removed lots of security codes to focus on question. user needs to be authenticated . i'm using gate and policy and some more things before response . thank you for your advise.

Please check once more whether this also happens on serving static files

@NicoHaase i have checked it before .loading all files that they are in public folder are ok. (using asset() function)

Browsers have also a limit of simultaneous connections. IIRC in firefox it is 8 by default

So, loading a bunch of  static files in parallel is possible, but loading a bunch of files through your PHP controller in parallel is not working?

@NicoHaase exactly.

Which HTTP server are you using?

@Olivier the project deployed on a shared hosting . it's using  Apache httpd (2.4.59) .

It may be a limitation set by the hosting provider. Did you try with a local server?

@Olivier in my local host its working fine and provider says there is no limitation.

What HTTP version are you using? This seems like a HTTP limitation.
HTTP/2 allows better use of the network by allowing multiple downloads in near parallel through multiplexing.
Similar issue Huge amount of images - HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2?.

I put 400 different image files in public directory and load them with asset() function in a loop. this was pretty efficient and all of 400 images loaded is 7 seconds (limited by internet bandwidth). there was no queue an pending.
